# if isset not set - php

Tags: php

```
if(isset($_POST['text1']) && isset($_POST['text2'])) {

echo "xxxxxx";
echo "yyyyyyyyyy";


} else {
?>
<form>

</form>


<?php

}


?>
```

When isset is not set I want the form shown and when submitted form not shown, using PHP.  This code when ! isset is activated, form is not shown, is it coding or syntax error

Comment: That seems to be what your code does. What's the question?

Comment: You guys should give 5 mins for someone to do some level of editing, rather than running a close ASAP

Comment: @nicholas its not performing as wanted

Comment: If you've sent the form, all POST-variable from that form will be set (unless they are checkboxes, but as you named them "text"…). Better to check for emptyness `if(!empty($_POST['text1']))`.

Answer (score 31):

> Just place a "!" in front of your if else statement's conditions,
>   Make sure that $_POST['text1'] and $_POST['text2'] are not already set in your php script itself.

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['text1']) && !isset($_POST['text2'])) {

echo "xxxxxx";
echo "yyyyyyyyyy";


} else {
?>
<form>

</form>


<?php

}


?>
```

Comment: Tried that which is why I came over here.  The form does not come if it is "!"

Comment: make sure that `$_POST['text1']` and `$_POST['text2']` are not already set in your php script itself.

Answer (score 5):

```
if(!(isset($_POST['text1']) && isset($_POST['text2']))) {
    echo "xxxxxx";
    echo "yyyyyyyyyy";
} else {
?>
<form>

</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: This does not work... if I remove the else {} it the form shows up, not otherwise.

Comment: <form> shows only when _POST['text1'] & _POSt['text2'] is defined

Comment: @Jean: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: When the page is loaded, the form is visible, once it is submitted, the results are echoed on to the page, the form is hidden.

Comment: @Jean: so your first one is correct and SHOULD work

Answer (score -2):

I got the problem, there was nothing with the code, the only problem was

Forgot to add php after

Silly me..

Thanks for all the assistance.